# Can I create an APK using C or C++?

Tags: android, c++, c

I want to know if I can develop an Android app using these two programming languages, and I can also use HTML for the interface?

Comment: You can do just *anything* that can be programmed with either of these languages.

Comment: If you're asking, you probably can't. But in theory, yes.

Comment: It's possible with the Android Native Development Kit (https://developer.android.com/ndk/index.html) albeit more complicated relative to developing for the JVM.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can. theoretically!   or you may even write the assembly for your apk directly.

Comment: even with pen and paper, write down the bits

Answer (score 1):

You can develop your app with Java and  Kotlin (Android SDK) and C/C++ (Android NDK) as native development languages.

You can also develop for both Android and iOS apps with C# (Xamarin or Unity3D - for games) and Javascript/html (a lot of frameworks - as Phonegap, Sencha Touch, React Native, etc) as hybrid applications.

Comment: Don't forget Dart.